# How to Create Transparent Logo

Tags: 13.10

How am I suppose to create a logo with a transparent background using GIMP in ubuntu studio 13.10. I have tried making one several times but to no avail a white background is still always there.

Comment: I don't see how this is an Ubuntu question as gimp is the same on all platforms but you may want to take a look [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Transparent-Image-Using-Gimp)

Answer (score 2):

If you want an image to have any transparency you'll need to save it as a PNG. Jpegs don't support transparency.

Under your save as menu either change the file extension to .png or select png from the file type drop down menu as shown.

[image]

Comment: On `Gimp 2.8`, you would `export` to PNG .